# Is moksha guaranteed for everyone?

Tags: moksha, yuga

I would like to know whether moksha is guaranteed for everyone i.e. everyone at some point is liberated from the cycle of birth and death.

To be clear, if not in this birth, he will be re-born and he can try it the next time. So this process continues on.

Now, my question is how long does this process go on? Does it go on till the end of the yuga or a yuga cycle (i.e 1 cycle of 4 yugas) or one kalpa or one Bramha year or the life time of Bramha or as long as he realizes and get moksha no matter how many Bramhas are created?

Is moksha guaranteed for everyone at some point?

Comment: Yes absolutely everyone is guaranteed to get Moksha! :) advaitistically it is believed that everything all of creation is a DREAM. Thus there really is NOONE else but God. Just like how in a dream we spring multiple creations into existence and then pull them back again God brings up multiple creations and pulls it all back again. Thus the Mokha is just a case of realizing that we are not the body mind but Brahman! Great saints say that once a man is done playing in His dream or experiencing the karmas then His MIND naturally goes towards God and He returns to God or gets liberated or BLISS:).

Comment: Every one is elgible for moksha, but it not guaranteed. Moksha can be granted by the supreme Lord only after all the Karmas are exhausted. There is nothing called return to godhead or jiva becoming god or Jiva is god, because, if Jiva were god then how did it get caught in this mire of transmigration and karmas? Jiva was never with God nor was it it god in the first place. Jiva and Paramatma are separate entities and even after realizing that we are not the body etc, it cannot be classified as moksha as the soul is still entagled in the body.

Comment: The famous Annamacharya (15 th century poet and author of many songs on Lord Venkateshwara, numbering around 30,000) who is considered as "telugu pada kavita pitamaha" says in one of his famous songs that "there is no guarantee that one will be liberated if you one keeps saying "SoHAM". But Annamacharya says that the sure pill and remedy for gaining moksha is "Dasoham".

Comment: Here is the annamacharya kirtana -                          sOhambani kondaru dAsOhambani kondaru sAhasa vruttula renDu terangula sakala vivEkulu bhajinturu dEhadhAriyai dAsOhambani tEri SukuDu meelOgalase sOhapu bhAvana sarva jagattula jupinadE pramANamu ||                                                                              Some learned pundits say that individual self (jeevatma) and the supreme soul are same (Soham). But Some say that self is sub-servient (Dasoham) to the supreme soul. Great sage Suka Surrendered and worshipped you and merged with you. What proof others can give?

Comment: wow 'dasoham' sounds like a wonderful and humbling mantra @Krishna! Thanks for sharing! please put it as an answer I am sure it would be beneficial for all :) Sir

Comment: @Sai, you speak beautiful words as well. Be careful about that dasoham :) Even Lord Krishna competes for that and drives Arjuna's chariot, carries messages for Yudhishtira, washes Sudama's feet etc. He comes as Lord Caitanya to fully experience that position of being a servant of the Lord and He says 'gopi-bhartu pada-kamalayor dasa-dasanudasah' - 'I am a servant of servant of Krishna's servant!'

Comment: @srinivasacaryadasa thank you :)! That quote by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is very touching and powerful! created a deep impact in the heart :). Thank you for sharing that! Serving God not only removes our egos and attachments but also makes us look deeper into things, what does God really want, what do we really want, thus whether Advaita or Dvaita or Vaishnava or Shiva devotee, serving God is one of the many wonderful paths to Liberation indeed!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, everyone gets moksha but how long it takes is up to you. If you do not get it by the end of a kalpa, your jiva gets 'recycled' to the next kalpa. There is no guarantee that it takes one or two or three or.....many kalpas.

From an pure advaita standpoint, you are already free. You cannot attain that which is eternal if you yourself were not already that. "Moksha cannot have a beginning and be eternal." (Mandukya Upanishad Gaudapada's Karika IV. 30.) Every soul (jiva) is a part of the Divine, none can be deprived or destroyed of what they really are. Everyone will attain to that which they are already.

From a relative standpoint, everything in this world is the result of cause and effect, and all cause in this world is relative and there is no action that can result in a permanent reaction.

As long as a soul (jiva) has desires, rebirth will occur. (Gita 2. 42-44, 2. 62-63. and 3. 37.) There is no end to rebirth so long as the objects of the world are desired.

A person who allows tamasic desires to take hold of him must go through even more innumerable births - Gita (16. 7-20.) "...Having fallen into the wombs of the demons and being deluded from birth to birth, they never attain Me, O son of Kunti, but go farther down to the lowest state."

There is a wonderful story (Brahmavaivarta Purana, Krishna-janma Khanda 47. 50-161.) of a brahmin 'boy' who appeared at Indra's court one day. While talking together, a procession of ants made an appearance and walked across the floor in military fashion 4 meters wide. The 'boy' paused and stared at them and then starting laughing. When Indra asked him why he was laughing, the 'boy' replied that each one of the ants was a former Indra, but after many rebirths had become an ant. The army was an army of former Indras.

How many births is up to you, how many kalpas is up to you. Give up desires.

Comment: This is more of a comment like question rather then an answer, so can you elaborate your answer with details?

Comment: Draft your answer nicely, add that to your answer if its related to the question.

Comment: But when the soul has entered all the life forms (cat, dog,human etc), is a life form repeated again? Also, some say (though I ain't sure) the soul created during one Bramha period cannot enter another physical body during another Bramha period? Is it right?

Comment: @JavaTechnical you can repeat, it's up to you whether you repeat or not. Even if you do karmic worship and attain the status of Indra or Brahma, you must be reborn. If born as Brahma for a kalpa, at the end of the kalpa Brahma is reborn in the physical world depending upon his karma...Lord Krishna has said the only sure way out is to give up desires........without giving up desires it is  unending births....

Comment: +1 Your answer is knowledgeable. But "Giving up desires" is difficult to define. If I think of making a computer program, is it considered as a *desire*? If yes, then someone has made this program called "stackexchange" where we are discussing. This discussion won't be possible without someone 'desiring' to make a program. If no, then what is a *desire*?

Comment: @iammilind Giving up desires and what is desire is easy to define. Read Gita II. 47 - 72.

Comment: Have we all taken infinite births in the past or finite births ?