# Sannyasa after death

Tags: scripture, death, sannyasa

I hope you can help me as searching on Google has not helped that much. My father passed away in February. I wondered whether anyone knew whether the soul can take Sannyasa? My father identified with Hinduism and was cremated (by chance) on Mahashivaratri. I just hope someone can answer my question or direct me to any texts that may help me.

Comment: Personal advice questions and dream analysis questions are off-topic for our site.

Comment: After death the Jivatma or individual soul moves along the three paths i.e. ., Devayana, Pitruyana, and the cycle of birth and death according to the his past karmas. After self-realisation in some birth he merges with Brahman i.e. supreme Lord. So soul repeat this process until Moksha (liberation from birth and death). He do not take sanyasa , the sanyasa of soul itself in other words  is Moksha.

Comment: Hello - sorry if any offence was taken. I am sure you understand my predicament and I appreciate your feedback. Could you recommend where I can read more about Devayana, Pitruyana and cycle of birth and death? Thanks

Comment: @LucyStroud You might be interested in reading this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2179/647 and this too: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3974/647

Comment: Thank you very much- I am looking after her :) I will read those posts! Thanks so again all your help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can read at https://www.iskconpress.com/books/bbd

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question. Hindu scriptures warn everyone to start working for moksha while in good health. It is too late once death arrives.

**Number of births and importance of human birth**

> In the eighty four lacs of bodies of creatures **one does not acquire
>   true knowledge anywhere unless one is born as a man.**
>
> Here, after thousands of crores of births a creature obtains human
>   form only sometime due to aggregate of virtue.
>
> **Having obtained a rare human form he should endeavour for moksha. If
>   he does not endeavour for it, there can be no greater sinner in the
>   world.**
>
> Born in the most beautiful human form he incurs the sin of slaying a
>   Brahmin if he neglects his self.
>
> **Without human body it is not possible to obtain the supreme goal. One
>   should be, therefore, very cautious to guard wealth in the form of his
>   body and perform  good actions**.
>
> ……
>
> **So far as this body remains intact he should practice dharma.** One is a
>   perfect fool who digs a well only when the house is on fire.

*[Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter XLIX]*